# Change maven plugin configuration in runtime

Tags: java, maven, plugins, runtime, maven-plugin

I have two maven plugins, **A** and **B**, where **A** is defined *before* **B**.

In the execution of A I want to change a certain configuration of B before it is executed, the two plugins are configured in the same phase (compile).

In the code of plugin A, I get the plugin to which I want to change the configuration:

```
List<Plugin> plugins = project.getBuildPlugins().stream()
            .filter(plugin -> plugin.getKey().equals("cz.habarta.typescript-generator:typescript-generator-maven-plugin"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Plugin plugin = plugins.get(0);
```

where project is a **MavenProject** instance.

```
for (PluginExecution t: plugin.getExecutions ()) {
  if (t.getPhase (). equals ("compile")) {
    Xpp3Dom config = (Xpp3Dom) t.getConfiguration ();
    t.setConfiguration (changeConfig (config));
  } else {
    System.out.println ("Not compile phase");
  }
}
```

The method **changeConfig ()** changes the current configuration and returns a new one.

The configuration *is changed*, but this change is not taken by the execution of plugin B.

Any subjection?

***Update:***

The process is as follows, the plugin **A** scans the project dependencies, for each dependency that meets a series of conditions, the following block must be added to the plugin **B** configuration:

```
<moduleDependency>
         <importFrom> value1 </importFrom>
         <importAs> value2 </importAs>
         <infoJson> value3 </infoJson>
          <npmPackageName> value4 </npmVersionRange>
</moduleDependency>
```

The n blocks are added within the following configuration element of plugin B:

```
<moduleDependencies>
   ...
</moduleDependencies>
```

[Information about the configuration element of plugin B](http://www.habarta.cz/typescript-generator/maven/typescript-generator-maven-plugin/generate-mojo.html#moduleDependencies)

The problem is that the new configuration is not taken by plugin B.

Any subjection?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is cleaner and easier to set certain properties inside the first plugin and use these properties in the configuration of the second plugin.

Comment: The problem is that the business logic we have is a bit complicated.
The plugin A, scans the jars (dependencies) of the project, to extract information from own modules.
That information will become part of the configuration of plugin B, plugin B is a plugin that is not its own.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "plugin B is a plugin that is not its own"?

Comment: Plugin A is our own development, plugin B belongs to third parties.

Comment: Ok, but isn't Plugin B parametrized through a `<configuration>` block in the POM? Couldn't you just add some properties here (like `${myspecialconf}`) and then fill these properties through plugin A ?

Comment: In the update section I explained the problem a little more.